# Isotope not working after I replace a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I have a jQuery post that replaces a div with updated products.  The grid is formatted with isotope but I can't figure out how to make it re-format the grid after update.

```
$.post(url, function(data) {

    $('#product_list').first().replaceWith(data.products);

}).always($('#product_list').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.product-thumb-info-list'
}));
```

If I run the `isotope()` from console it will re-order the grid nicely so I guess it is firing too early.

How can I get it to apply to the grid immediately after the post function replaces the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change on how you handle your `always` method to this instead:

```
$.post(url, function(data) {
  $('#product_list').first().replaceWith(data.products);
}).always(function() {
  $('#product_list').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.product-thumb-info-list'
  })
});
```

Comment: Now it is intermittently screwing with layout, I added a timeout and that fixes it but makes the page jump.  Need to figure out how to execute once browser has finished rendering :S

Comment: @Guerrilla have you insert your code above inside `$(function() { /** code goes here  */ });` ?

Comment: yeah there is something weird going on.  Isotope re-sizes the container and ads in absolute positions for everything, if it executes at wrong time then it gets messed up.  If I add a delay then it starts to work but if replace happens at wrong time it gets screwed up again as the container gets its height set too small and everything gets crushed.

Comment: @Guerrilla have a look at this [link](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/methods.html#relayout). There you have an option to relayout or reload the items. There's also a method where you can remove items then `prepend` new ones which an alternative for your `replaceWith`

Comment: Thanks, checking it out now.  I added a break point and realised that occasionally it fires before images have rendered and that is why the height gets messed up.  The images have a height: auto and width: 100% so I think sometimes the DOM hasn't worked out exactly how tall they are and isotope sets height to height of div without an image.